# How can memory be freed for Inkscape?

Tags: dell, memory, inkscape, svg

I'm working on a large map with Inkscape on a Dell Vostro 1510.

Computer specifications are:
*Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5670  @ 1.80GHz

Total Memory: 3014 MiB (70% free)

Total Swap: 3060 MiB (85% free)

Cached: 660 MiB

Active: 798 MiB

Inactive: 768 MiB*
Graphic card: Intel GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphic Controller

Working on this map is very slow, I cannot do the slightest thing without waiting for 5 min until the new event is repainted on screen.

I'm a bit perplexed though: I may not have a top computer but it should be able to perform better I think. The map is working on is large, there are many vectors, but it seems nothing compared to viewing 3D, playing a movie or a flash animation. So I'm suspecting Inkscape enjoys a limited amount of memory--especially because other programs perform well in the meantime. So is there a way to free up memory for Inkscape so I can work fast?

Thanks.

Comment: I've the same problem. Specially when i'm trying to work with pictures and pdf's..I've tryed Inkscape on diferent machines, with diferent capacityes and the result was the same.

Comment: @Jorge Pinho: I found out it is a common issue indeed. It is apparently a memory leak issue. (I am going to try Xara until answers come).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not an issue of too little RAM, but of a CPU bottleneck? Anyway, what you can try, if you handle a large drawing, is to view the whole thing in `Outline` or `No Filters` mode (See View-Display Mode in the menu).

http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/View-Misc.html#View-Misc-OutlineMode

Comment: Yep, but right now i am working on some texture overlay and i really can't stick to outline :( (Also i wanted to post a similar answer with links but couldn't because of low reputation). Thanks.

Comment: What can you not do exactly? Links in answers would probably fall under new user restrictions and only need 10 rep. http://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user

Comment: I'll take this answer, sorry for delay. I've read somewhere that Inkscape does not use threading and therefore uses only one CPU. Outline mode is a poor workaround, but that's the best there is.